# Java - delete selected row from tablemodel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I need delete deleted row from my arraylist...

```
private GuiIO guiIO;
private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
private List<Book> zoz;


public MyGui() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(this.getRootPane());
    this.guiIO = new GuiIO();

    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Znacka", "Model", "Najazdene", "Rok vyroby", "Vykon", "Cena"}, 0);
    this.tblTabulka.setModel(tableModel);
    this.tblTabulka.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    tblTabulka.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    TableRowSorter rowSorter = new TableRowSorter(tableModel);
    zoz = guiIO.getAllBook();
}
```

my function for delete row from model:

```
   private void btnClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    final int sectedRowIndex = this.tblTabulka.getSelectedRow();
    this.tableModel.removeRow(sectedRowIndex);
    zoz = guiIO.getAllBook();
}

 public List getAllBook() {
    List all_book = new ArrayList<Book>();

    for (Containerable item = this.book.getFirst();
            item!=null;
            item = this.book.getNext())
        all_book.add(item);
    return all_book;
}
```

but i need delete it from my private List zoz;

how can i do it?

Comment: `but i need delete it from my private List zoz` - don't keep a private List. Don't keep data in two places as you will have trouble syncing the data as you have found out. All the data should be kept in the TableModel. All updates to the data should be done via the TableModel.

Answer (score 3):

I need delete it from my private List zoz?

```
 zoz.remove(sectedRowIndex); // if table is not sortable
```

Note:

- Do not initialize the list again after deleting the selected row.
- `DefaultTableModel` is not populating from the list
- put a check `tblTabulka.getSelectedRow() != -1` before deleting the row whether row is selected or not?

---

Use `Map` instead of `List` something like

```
Map<String,Book> books = new HashMap<String,Book>();
```

where you can make isbn or id as key.

---

Sample code:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // check for selected row first
        if (tblTabulka.getSelectedRow() != -1) {

            // get value of first cell of selected row
            String isbn= (String)tableModel.getValueAt(tblTabulka.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            books.remove(isbn);

            // remove from the model also
            model.removeRow(tblTabulka.getSelectedRow());
        }
    }
});
```